# add the push notification feature to your App ID

Tags: xcode, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, google-cloud-firestore, device

I am creating an application with ionic. I already have the certificates downloaded and I wanted to receive the notifications using the xcode simulator, but I do not receive them. In the 'Capabilities' section, in the 'push notification' section I have the error:

- 'add the push notification feature to your App ID'

==================================================

Do not use xcode very well. I hope someone can help me.

a greeting

Comment: You have to add the feature on https://developer.apple.com.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 'add the push notification feature to your App ID'

As it states, go to developer apple portal to add the push notification feature to your App ID and regenerate your provisioning profile.

https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/identifier/bundle

You also have to generate a APNs Auth Key to make push notification and some coding is needed in your app. You can reference the following tutorial.

https://www.raywenderlich.com/156966/push-notifications-tutorial-getting-started

Comment: @ÍñigoEnriqueHernández yes, you have to register notification settings with a valid deviceToken from a real device.

Comment: thank you very much! It has been a great help to me.